# Python Mypy fails on Decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, mypy

I'm trying to create a decorate. When I apply the decorator to a method in a class in python, it errors out with the following error:

```
score.py: note: In class "Scorer":
score.py:31:6: error: Untyped
decorator makes function "score" untyped  [misc]
        @process_without_columns(ignore_cols=ignore)
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I resolve this? I've tried updating the original decorator and adding all the types, but it's not working

Decorator

```
"""Decoractor Functions."""

from typing import Any, Callable, List, Union
from pandas import DataFrame, concat


# Decorator to process DataFrame with ignore columns
def process_without_columns(
    ignore_cols: List[str], final_cols_order: Union[List[str], None] = None
) -> Callable:
    """
    Decorate to process a DataFrame, removing specified ignore columns, and then joining them back.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ignore_cols: List[str]
        List of column names to ignore during processing.
    final_cols_order: Union[List[str], None]
        List specifying the desired order of columns in the final DataFrame.
        If None, the original DataFrame's column order will be used. Default is None.

    Returns
    -------
        decorator_process: Decorator function that processes the DataFrame.
    """

    def decorator_process(func: Callable) -> Callable:
        def inner(self, data_df: DataFrame, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> DataFrame:
            """
            Inner function that performs the actual processing of the DataFrame.

            Parameters
            ----------
                data_df: DataFrame
                    DataFrame to be processed.
                *args
                    args passed into inner function
                **kwargs
                    Kwargs passed into inner function


            Returns
            -------
                DataFrame: Processed DataFrame with the original columns
            """
            ignore_df = data_df[
                ignore_cols
            ]  # Extract the ignore columns as a separate DataFrame
            data_df = data_df.drop(
                columns=ignore_cols
            )  # Remove the ignore columns from the original DataFrame

            # Process the DataFrame (smaller DataFrame without ignore columns)
            processsed_df = func(self, data_df, *args, **kwargs)

            # Join back the processed DataFrame with the ignore columns DataFrame
            processsed_df = concat([processsed_df, ignore_df], axis=1)

            # Reorder DataFrame columns if final_cols_order is specified
            if final_cols_order is not None:
                processsed_df = processsed_df[final_cols_order]

            return processsed_df

        return inner

    return decorator_process
```

Execution of it

```
from typing import Any, List

from mydecorator import process_without_columns

ignore: List[Any] = []


class Scorer(Base):
    """Class."""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """Initialize class."""

    @process_without_columns(ignore_cols=ignore)
    def score(self, data_df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
        """Score function."""
        return data_df
```

How can I resolve the `Untyped decorator makes function "score" untyped` error?

Comment: You need to add parameters to `Callable` to indicate that the decorated function has the same type as the original.  See the dupe for links to docs with examples.

Comment: So.. basically replace `Callable` w/ `F = TypeVar('F', bound=Callable[..., Any])`